# Errors when importing Mahout's maven resource to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, mahout

I'm trying to import **Mahout**'s maven resource to eclipse, but i meet these errors:

[image]

I have tried google but it doesn't help.

Eclipse : Helios Service Release 1

Maven : External Maven 3.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to deal with this? I haven't had any success with the answers posted, and if you've figured it out it would be great if you posted what you've found.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: If I try to play with latest stable release ( Mahout 0.7 ) and not the latest snapshot that the official site recommends for downloading, I experience the same error.

Follow step-by-step this link: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/buildingmahout.html

After doing this and re-importing mahout, these errors you noticed go away.

**Notice**: Before compiling the code in the right way (as stated at the link above), I have followed the instructions from here:

http://domengrabec.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/installing-maven-on-eclipse/

**Q**: If anyone could help me with this related issue:
[Include classes of Mahout math libraries of both core & math folders - Eclipse - Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741037/include-classes-of-mahout-math-libraries-of-both-core-math-folders-eclipse) , I would be grateful.

Comment: I was not successful at getting this to import after doing all of the maven install and compile operations suggested on cwiki.apache.org.

Comment: What exactly was your problem?

Comment: I performed all of the command line maven install/compile operations, but doing a "Maven project import" came up with the same error. I finally just did a mvn eclipse:eclipse install and imported it as an eclipse project. I guess I'm kind of new to Maven, so the variations between plugins and command line and all seem very complex.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea on how to fix this if you have imported Mahout 0.7 and followed exactly the above instructions.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to build mahout in a different way,
first install m2e plugin for eclipse, then you can create  maven project. You can make the run configuration (package) after that to make sure everything is fine.

The important part is that you have the pom.xml in the project so you have to add the dependencies of mahout that you want.

You can get the dependencies from searching on google " name of the dependency in mahout api".

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by manually applying the patch in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1043 to 0.7 sources (changes pom.xml files and src/conf/driver.classes.conf )

just one note, do not remove the groupid in distribution/pom.xml

launch an external mvn eclipse:clean and update the projects. All errors are gone when workspace is rebuilt