# Mahout importing into eclipse with errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, mahout

Im new to mahout and am. Using mahout version 0.5 on ubuntu 12.04, and running hadoop 0.20 on the system and maven has been installed on eclipse as a plugin. using the commands bin/mahout on command line seems to work fine. Im having problem importing it into eclipse

[I have used this link to help import the mahout project as a existing maven project into eclipse.](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/buildingmahout.html)

I followed the steps as told on the site. First i did
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk

then this created a truck folder in the mahout directory. I then did
mvn install

Now imported the project into eclipse only to find it filled with errors. Can someone help me out why this is happening..

P.S: i referred to [Errors when importing Mahout's maven resource to eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282737/errors-when-importing-mahouts-maven-resource-to-eclipse) also but no answer seems to be posted

Comment: If you are using Mahout 0.5, why are you checking out from trunk?

Comment: i tried importing the mahout root directory as well it stills gets imported with errors